# Jquery - getJSON 401 "bug?"

Tags: jquery, getjson, http-status-code-401

i have a problem with the jquery getjson.

**This code works**

```
$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/USERNAME.json?count=10&callback=?', function(twitter_data)
{
    alert('works');          
});
```

**and this code not?**

```
$.getJSON('https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json?callback=?', function(twitter_data)
{
   alert('no alert ?');
});
```

But why? Any ideas?

**example - >** http://jsfiddle.net/4wWJW/2/

**Thanks** in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've updated a version of your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/4wWJW/9/

Unfortunately the example you give includes a `oauth_nonce` which I believe is a one-time authentication token.  So unfortunately this won't work.  You'll need to be authenticated with your account to debug.

Instead of using `jQuery.getJSON` I've used the long-hand call to `jQuery.ajax`.  This allows an error handler to be used.  When the ajax call succeeds the `success` function is called, otherwise the `error` function is called.

I can see in this case that the call is not successful, e.g. a status code of 200 is not returned, and therefore the `error` function is called.

You could interrogate the jqXHR object and the other parameters to the error function to see what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

`https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json` returns 401 status code. You didn't [send any credentials](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554643/Authentication) in the request.

Comment: That is not the problem. When i send this with credentials, the alert(); didn start too. But why? -> http://jsfiddle.net/4wWJW/4/

Comment: Well, you asked about a 401 error. That's what the 401 means, no credentials.

Comment: Ok, but the request is finished. Why did the alert(); not start?

Comment: @Peter, I don't see any `callback=?` parameter in your request string. Are you sure that you get `JSONP` from the server? Use FireBug to see exactly what's sent and received from the server.

Comment: @Peter, it doesn't work because the url you are trying to fetch: https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=bXpp8C7Gx09K4HFi8uDjCg&oauth_nonce=ae5fdf0b661983b6ff4e898597c65794&oauth_signature=zqsNDh9MB/er8YsLfjll9VKXZyA%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1299597357&oauth_token=250576060-mzfeaAuD5PuSmSUwCtrU3tvfR4TejX1MUe2veX6B&oauth_version=1.0&callback=abc returns HTTP 401 Unauthorized which means incorrect or not supplied credentials. So until you get this url properly showing in your browser address bar your JSONP call won't work.

Answer (score 0):

from [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the JSON file contains a syntax error, the request will    usually fail silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON data for this reason. JSON is a    data-interchange format with syntax rules that are stricter than those of JavaScript's object literal notation. For example, all strings represented in JSON, whether they are properties or values, must be enclosed in double-quotes.

I would guess that returning an error would be equivalent to returning invalid JSON as far as jQuery is concerned?